# Filter new content to only display specific divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

to load more content inside my page, I'm retrieving an external page link with the jQuery.get() function.

I can retrieve all the page, however, when I'm trying to filter the result to get only the ".container_journal_post" divs, I can't make it work.
Your help is welcome.

Here is my current HTML code:

```
<div id="related_projects" class="gridalicious">
    <article><div class="container_journal_post"> post 1 </div></article>
    <article><div class="container_journal_post"> post 2 </div></article>
</div>
```

Here is my external page HTML code:

```
<div id="related_projects" class="gridalicious">
    <article><div class="container_journal_post"> post 34 </div></article>
    <article><div class="container_journal_post"> post 35 </div></article>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var pageNum = parseInt($("#current_page")[0]["innerHTML"]);
    // Get the page number 
    var max = parseInt($("#max_num_pages")[0]["innerHTML"]);
    // Get the maximum number of the blog section.
    var nextLink = $("#pagination .next")[0]["href"];
    // Get The link of the next page of posts.

    // A button where the user is cliking to load more posts
    $('#append').click(function(){
        makeboxes();
    }); 

    makeboxes = function() {
        var boxes = new Array;

        $.get(nextLink, function(data) {
           // console.log(data);
           // Return the "nextLink" HTML DOM
           // Can't cut it correctly 
           // console.log($(data));
           // Return 100 items

           // I would like to get something like this:
                $(data).filter( 'article' ).each(
                function( key, value ) { 
//                  value has to be equal at 
//                  <div class="container_journal_post"> post 34 </div>
                    boxes.push(value);
                }

            );
            // load at the end of the div the new boxes
            jQuery( "#related_projects" ).gridalicious( 'append', boxes );
        });
    }
});
```

Result wanted after the "makebox" function is called:

```
<div id="related_projects" class="gridalicious">
    <article><div class="container_journal_post"> post 1 </div></article>
    <article><div class="container_journal_post"> post 2 </div></article>
    <article><div class="container_journal_post"> post 34 </div></article>
    <article><div class="container_journal_post"> post 35 </div></article>
</div>
```

Comment: $('<div>').html(data).find('article').each( function( key, value ) { 
     boxes.push(value);
                }
            );

Answer (score 0):

you might use the load function of jquery:

`$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');`
whereas `#container` is the selector for the content being fetched

(see [jquery load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

Comment: Unfortunatly, I had allready try this, look what I have done:

 var result = $("#related_projects").load(nextLink + ' .container_journal_post'); 
 var test = result[0]["children"];

Comment: Inside the console, I get this: 

[div#item00Higg.galcolumn, div#item10Higg.galcolumn, div#item20Higg.galcolumn, div#clear0Higg, item: function, namedItem: function]
0: article.container_journal_post
1: article.container_journal_post
2: article.container_journal_post
3: article.container_journal_post
4: article.container_journal_post
5: article.container_journal_post
6: article.container_journal_post
7: article.container_journal_post
8: article.container_journal_post
9: article.container_journal_post
10: article.container_journal_post
11: article.container_journal_post
length: 12

Comment: the load function actually fills the fetched content directly to the element specified in $('#result')..... therefore you would have to parse it into the result array by: var result = $('#result').children('.container_journal_post');

Comment: But, I don't know how I can get these values because  var test = result[0]["children"][0];
return : <div class="galcolumn" id="item0703zp" ></div>

Comment: use that snippet to get all '<article>' contents:
$('div#related_projects').children().filter( 'article' ).each( function(){
       alert($(this).html()); 
});

see: http://jsfiddle.net/NdDYw/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but, I need to filter the new page info, not my current page.
Here are an exemple http://jsfiddle.net/YwXmw/4/
(the other page is here)
Note: we can't retrieve a jsfiddle.net page
+1 for your comment