# Copy inside a variable the html of an external link

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Here is my previous question: [Filter new content to only display specific divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305271/filter-new-content-to-only-display-specific-divs)

I would like to get and copy some content from an external page inside a variable.
To perform it, I'm using the jquery.get function.

```
// This code is adding to the div the content
$('.result').html(data);
```

I would like to save the content inside a variable to be able to get only informations that I want

```
   $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
          // Add to the <div class="result"> the html of data
          $('.result').html(data);
          // I would like some thing like this
          var result = the html of data 
   });
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly is the question/problem here?

Comment: I want to get inside the variable result the html code of data:

var result =  .html(data);

Comment: `data` is an html string.  `var result` outside of `$.get` and `result = data`

Comment: thanks astex, will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data variable **IS** the actual HTML you want...

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function (data) {
    var result = data;
    alert(result);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dXN28/)

---

If you then want to use jquery on that HTML data, you must convert it to a JQuery object...

```
var htmlElement = $(result);
//can now do htmlElement.find(...
```

[Here is an example that pulls the date from the BBC news website](http://jsfiddle.net/dXN28/1/)

Comment: Not for getting the html into a `result` variable, I'd say.

Comment: @Bergi: Well it was hard to tell what he wanted at the time, I assumed that his code just wasted working properly for some reason and that he was trying to put the HTML into an element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I can't still extracting the result how I want.
var boxes = new Array;
$.get('ajax/test.html', function (data) {
var result = data.find('article').each( function( key, value ) { 
                   boxes.push(value);
                }
            );
            $("#related_projects").gridalicious('append', boxes);
              
        });
        
      
    }  + 1 for your answer

Comment: Working perfectly =)
Thanks a lot